# Sorting pairs or more of ints. Is there a better way than arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, dictionary

I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this, work with pairs of numbers. I'm working through the problems on CodeAbbey.  This one was

> sort these numbers, then print out their original index location.

I did it like this.  ( I'm still learning. )

```
public static void bSort(int[][] a) {
    boolean sorted = false;
    int temp;
    int temp2;

    while (!sorted) {
        int counter = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
            if (a[i][0] > a[i + 1][0]) {
                temp = a[i][0];
                temp2 = a[i][1];
                a[i][0] = a[i + 1][0];
                a[i + 1][0] = temp;

                a[i][1] = a[i + 1][1];
                a[i + 1][1] = temp2;
                counter++;
            }
        }
        if (counter == 0) {
            sorted = true;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(a[i][1] + " ");
    }
}
```

I kept running into this as I was searching:
[Sort a Map<Key, Value> by values (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java) but I haven't worked with maps yet.

Comment: More efficient, smarter.  I realized after the fact that this might be a better question for Code Review.  This just seemed clunky to me and I figured there might be a better way to go about it.

Comment: You can create a similar array to load the original index, I think this way is very simple and fast. If you have confuse with this idea,  I will give you some code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a class holding a pair of ints :

```
class Pair implements Comparable<Pair>{

    int number, index;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Pair other){
        return Integer.compare(number, other.number);
    }
}
```

Then you can sort an array of Pair like this :

```
Pair[] pairs = new Pair[]; // initialize with values
Arrays.sort(pairs);
```

This will sort an array or `Pair` according to `number` and if you iterate over it afterwards you can get the `index` of each `Pair`

Alternatively you can implement the `Comparator` interface outside the `Pair` class

```
class PairComparator implements Comparator<Pair> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Pair a, Pair b) {
        return Integer.compare(a.number, b.number);
    }
}
```

and use it like this

```
Arrays.sort(pairs, new PairComparator());
```

Comment: I agree with your solution but would like to recommend the use of Comparator interface instead of Comparable as good programming practice. With Comparable there is no modification to the main class(good programming practice) also you can sort on multiple attributes instead of just one compareTo.

Comment: As an aside, never rely on `a.number - b.number;` to compare two ints. Use `Integer.compare(a, b)` instead, which doesn't produce incorrect results.

Comment: @amanshivhare In this case it's perfectly justified to use `Comparable`, as it is the most natural ordering you can think of for this class.

Comment: @biziclop many thanks for the suggestion as it helped me spot 2 additional bugs in my code! In the first case I was comparing the same numbers and the second resulted in descending order! I guess one more reason I should rely on such methods and don't try to implement everything myself

Comment: I need to look at Comparable/Comparator, this was the first time I ran across them.  Thanks for all the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to solve any given problem. While it might seem a bit to take in early in your learning curve I suggest you get used to Java 8 streams and lambdas. Once you are used to them you'll find them a natural way of solving lots of problems.

So here's a stream based solution to your problem which I'll then explain:

```
void printSortedIndexes(int[] list) {
    IntStream.range(0, list.length).boxed()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(n -> list[n]))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

This can be interpreted as: make a stream of integers from 0 to the length of the list - 1, convert to a stream of `Integer` objects, sort them by comparing the integers at that index in the list and then print them out. I think that's a better way than storing the index and manually sorting them.

Comment: Having just come across lambdas, I definitely want to look at them.

Answer (score 0):

It at least is probably better than two parallel arrays of same length. "Probably" because `a[indices[i]]` - the **permutation** approach -, is a fine solution too.

Other answers already mention some approaches.

Your approach would more consequently use the pair `int[]`:

```
public static void bSort(int[][] a) {
    boolean sorted = false;
    int fromI = 0;
    while (!sorted) {
        boolean changed = false;
        for (int i = fromI; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
            int[] current = a[i];
            int[] next = a[i + 1];
            if (current[0] > next[0]) {
                int temp = current[0];
                int temp2 = current[1];
                current[0] = next[0];
                current[1] = next[1];
                next[0] = temp;
                next[1] = temp2;
                if (!changed) {
                    fromI = i;
                    changed = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if (!changed) {
            sorted = true;
        }
    }
    for (int[] current : a) {
        System.out.print(current[1] + " ");
    }
}
```

In the above:

- There is no penalty for declaring a variable in a loop, entirely identical.
- One could use `System.arrayCopy`.
- temp/temp2 could be one `int[]` too, but then better created outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

### Here is a solution using Maps

```
Map<Integer, Integer> toBeSorted = new HashMap<>();

toBeSorted.put(1, -2);
toBeSorted.put(2, -1);
toBeSorted.put(3, 8);
toBeSorted.put(4, 7);
toBeSorted.put(5, 6);
toBeSorted.put(6, 500);
toBeSorted.put(7, 4);
toBeSorted.put(8, 3);
toBeSorted.put(9, 2);
toBeSorted.put(10, 1);

final Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> comparator =

    new Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>>() {

  @Override
  public int compare(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> o1,
                     Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> o2) {
    return o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue());
  }

};//Comparator

//need a List to keep contract with Collections.sort()
final List<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> list =
    new ArrayList<>(toBeSorted.entrySet());

//invoke sort 
Collections.sort(list, comparator);

for(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : list) {
  System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " -> " + entry.getValue());
}
```

prints out:

```
1 -> -2
2 -> -1
10 -> 1
9 -> 2
8 -> 3
7 -> 4
5 -> 6
4 -> 7
3 -> 8
6 -> 500
```